# Vite-PWA-plugin how to add webpush (notifications)

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, vite, workbox, web-push

I had the `sw.js` which receive webpush notifications.
But recently I intalled vite-PWA-plugin and now i can't add notifications by default config.

How can i configure this `vite.config.ts` to add to generated `serviceWorker.js` webpush implementation?

`vite.config.ts`:

```js
import {defineConfig} from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

import path from 'path';
import {VitePWA} from "vite-plugin-pwa";

const manifest = {
    "theme_color"     : "#2B2B2B",
    "background_color": "#2B2B2B",
    "display"         : "standalone",
    "scope"           : "/",
    "start_url"       : "/farm",
    "name"            : "ColorBit",
    "short_name"      : "Mining",
    "description"     : "...",
    "icons"           : [
        {
            "src"  : "icons/icon-192x192.png",
            "sizes": "192x192",
            "type" : "image/png"
        },
        // ...
        {
            "src"    : "icons/maskable_icon.png",
            "sizes"  : "682x682",
            "type"   : "image/png",
            "purpose": "maskable"
        }
    ]
};

const getCache = ({ name, pattern, strategy = "CacheFirst" }: any) => ({
    urlPattern: pattern,
    handler: strategy,
    options: {
        cacheName: name,
        expiration: {
            maxEntries: 500,
            maxAgeSeconds: 60 * 60 * 24 * 60 // 2 months
        },
        cacheableResponse: {
            statuses: [0, 200]
        }
    }
});

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input  : [ 'resources/js/app.tsx',],
            refresh: true,
        }),
        react({
            fastRefresh: false
        }),
        VitePWA({
            registerType: 'autoUpdate',
            outDir      : path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
            manifest    : manifest,
            manifestFilename: 'manifest.webmanifest', // Change name for app manifest
            injectRegister  : false, // I register SW in app.ts, disable auto registration

            workbox         : {
                globDirectory: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'), // Directory for caching
                globPatterns : [
                    '{build,images,sounds,icons}/**/*.{js,css,html,ico,png,jpg,mp4,svg}'
                ],
                navigateFallback: null, // Say that we don't need to cache index.html
                swDest       : 'public/serviceWorker.js',
                runtimeCaching: [
                    // Google fonts cache
                    getCache({
                        pattern: /^https:\/\/fonts\.googleapis\.com\/.*/i,
                        name: "google-fonts-cache",
                    }),
                    // Google fonts api cache
                    getCache({
                        pattern: /^https:\/\/fonts\.gstatic\.com\/.*/i,
                        name: "gstatic-fonts-cache"
                    }),
                    // Dynamic cache for assets in storage folder
                    getCache({
                        pattern: /.*storage.*/,
                        name: "dynamic-images-cache",
                    }),

                ]
            }
        })
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias     : {
            '@'          : path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/js'),
            '@hooks'     : path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/js/hooks'),
            '@assets'    : path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/js/assets/'),
            '@components': path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/js/components')
        },
        extensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.tsx', '.jsx'],
    },
});
```

Old webpush implementation in `sw.js`:

```js
// ^^^ Activate, Install, Fetch... ^^^

/* Webpush Notifications */

// Receive push notifications
self.addEventListener('push', function (e) {
    if (!(
        self.Notification &&
        self.Notification.permission === 'granted'
    )) {
        //notifications aren't supported or permission not granted!
        return;
    }

    if (e.data) {
        let message = e.data.json();
        e.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification(message.title, {
            body: message.body,
            icon: message.icon,
            actions: message.actions
        }));
    }
});

// Click and open notification
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
    event.notification.close();

    if (event.action === 'farm') clients.openWindow("/farm");
    else if (event.action === 'home') clients.openWindow("/");
    else if (event.action === 'training') clients.openWindow("/mining-training");
    else if (event.action === 'dns') clients.openWindow("/shops/dns");
    else if (event.action === 'ali') clients.openWindow("/shops/aliexpress");
    else clients.openWindow("/farm");
}, false);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should use the inject manifest parametr and write custom serviceWorker by workbox prepared methods (workbox documentation is very bad, i think so. You can use some methods from my config)

`vite.config.ts`:

```js
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    laravel({
      input: ['resources/js/app.tsx', ],
      refresh: true,
    }),
    react({
      fastRefresh: false
    }),
    VitePWA({
      registerType: 'autoUpdate',
      outDir: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
      manifest: manifest,
      manifestFilename: 'manifest.webmanifest', // Change name for app manifest
      injectRegister: false, // I register SW in app.ts, disable auto registration

      // HERE! For custom service worker
      srcDir: path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/js/'),
      filename: 'serviceWorker.js',
      strategies: 'injectManifest',

      workbox: {
        globDirectory: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
        globPatterns: [
          '{build,images,sounds,icons}/**/*.{js,css,html,ico,png,jpg,mp4,svg}'
        ],
      },
    })
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/js'),
      '@hooks': path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/js/hooks'),
      '@assets': path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/js/assets/'),
      '@components': path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/js/components')
    },
    extensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.tsx', '.jsx'],
  },

  // define: {
  //     // By default, Vite doesn't include shims for NodeJS/
  //     // necessary for React-joyride. And probably for another libs
  //     global: {},
  // },
});
```

`/resouces/js/serviceWorker.js`:

```js
import {ExpirationPlugin} from 'workbox-expiration';
import {createHandlerBoundToURL, precacheAndRoute, cleanupOutdatedCaches} from 'workbox-precaching';
import {registerRoute} from 'workbox-routing';
import {CacheFirst} from 'workbox-strategies';
import { CacheableResponsePlugin } from 'workbox-cacheable-response/CacheableResponsePlugin';

// Register precache routes (static cache)
precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST || []);

// Clean up old cache
cleanupOutdatedCaches();

// Google fonts dynamic cache
registerRoute(
    /^https:\/\/fonts\.googleapis\.com\/.*/i,
    new CacheFirst({
        cacheName: "google-fonts-cache",
        plugins: [
            new ExpirationPlugin({maxEntries: 500, maxAgeSeconds: 5184e3}),
            new CacheableResponsePlugin({statuses: [0, 200]})
        ]
    }), "GET");

// Google fonts dynamic cache
registerRoute(
    /^https:\/\/fonts\.gstatic\.com\/.*/i, new CacheFirst({
        cacheName: "gstatic-fonts-cache",
        plugins: [
            new ExpirationPlugin({maxEntries: 500, maxAgeSeconds: 5184e3}),
            new CacheableResponsePlugin({statuses: [0, 200]})
        ]
    }), "GET");

// Dynamic cache for images from `/storage/`
registerRoute(
    /.*storage.*/, new CacheFirst({
        cacheName: "dynamic-images-cache",
        plugins: [
            new ExpirationPlugin({maxEntries: 500, maxAgeSeconds: 5184e3}),
            new CacheableResponsePlugin({statuses: [0, 200]})
        ]
    }), "GET");

// Install and activate service worker
self.addEventListener('install', () => self.skipWaiting());
self.addEventListener('activate', () => self.clients.claim());

// Receive push notifications
self.addEventListener('push', function (e) {
    if (!(
        self.Notification &&
        self.Notification.permission === 'granted'
    )) {
        //notifications aren't supported or permission not granted!
        console.log('nononono')
        return;
    }

    if (e.data) {
        let message = e.data.json();
        e.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification(message.title, {
            body: message.body,
            icon: message.icon,
            actions: message.actions
        }));
    }
});

// Click and open notification
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
    event.notification.close();

    if (event.action === 'farm') clients.openWindow("/farm");
    else if (event.action === 'home') clients.openWindow("/");
    else if (event.action === 'training') clients.openWindow("/mining-training");
    else if (event.action === 'dns') clients.openWindow("/shops/dns");
    else if (event.action === 'ali') clients.openWindow("/shops/aliexpress");
    else if (event.action === 'avito') clients.openWindow("/avito");
    else if (event.action === 'friends') clients.openWindow("/friends");
    else if (event.action === 'locations') clients.openWindow("/locations");
    else if (event.action === 'vk-chat') clients.openWindow("https://vk.me/join/au1/k0nOTjLasxMO6wX50QuyPfYosyWdPEI=");
    else clients.openWindow(event.action); // Open link from action
}, false);
```

vite-pwa-plugin has only some info about opportunity to create webpush - [documentation](https://vite-pwa-org.netlify.app/workbox/inject-manifest.html#server-push-notifications)

I found some code for service-worker in this [repo](https://github.com/jeffposnick/yt-playlist-notifier) and copy some code from old default generated by vite.config.ts config

Answer (score 0):

Had to do this today with Firebase notifications. Here's what I did in case this helps someone else out in the future

Created the service worker file (included full version because I found it hard to find information on how to add notificiations)

```
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.0/firebase-app.js");
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.0/firebase-messaging.js");

if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker
        .register("../firebase-messaging-sw.js")
        .then(function (registration) {
            console.log("Registration successful, scope is:", registration.scope);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log("Service worker registration failed, error:", err);
        });
}

// Initialize the Firebase app in the service worker by passing the generated config
var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "your apiKey",
    authDomain: "your authDomain",
    projectId: "you get the point by now right?",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: "",
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Retrieve firebase messaging
const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.onBackgroundMessage(function (payload) {
    console.log("Received background message ", payload);

    const notificationTitle = payload.notification.title;
    const notificationOptions = {
        body: payload.notification.body,
        icon: "/images/yourLogo.png",
    };

    self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
});
```

In my (React) app I registered for foreground notifications like this

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getMessaging, getToken, onMessage } from "firebase/messaging";

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "your apiKey",
    authDomain: "your authDomain",
    projectId: "you get the point by now right?",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: "",
};

const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const messaging = getMessaging(firebaseApp);

export const getFirebaseToken = (setTokenFound) => {
    return getToken(messaging, {
        vapidKey: "key is generated for you on firebase",
    })
        .then((currentToken) => {
            if (currentToken) {
                console.log("current token for client: ", currentToken);
                setTokenFound(true);
                // Track the token -> client mapping, by sending to backend server
                // show on the UI that permission is secured
            } else {
                console.log("No registration token available. Request permission to generate one.");
                setTokenFound(false);
                // shows on the UI that permission is required
            }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log("An error occurred while retrieving token. ", err);
            // catch error while creating client token
        });
};

export const onMessageListener = () =>
    new Promise((resolve) => {
        onMessage(messaging, (payload) => {
            console.log("payload", payload);
            resolve(payload);
        });
    });
```

and called it in my App.tsx file like this. So now we get a prompt requesting  notification permission and we can see the user token in console if they accept

```
    getFirebaseToken(setTokenFound);
    isTokenFound ? console.log("Token found") : console.log("Token not found");

    onMessageListener()
        .then((payload) => {
            toast.success(payload.notification.title, payload.notification.body);
            console.log(payload);
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log("failed: ", err));
```

In my `vite.config.js` at the top level of the object I return from `defineConfig()` all I had to do was import the script like so

```
workbox: {
    importScripts: ["./firebase-messaging-sw.js"],
},
```

This last bit took me the longest to figure out....hope it helps someone